# Enable long press on Exoplayer FFWD and RWD on Android TV

Tags: exoplayer, android-tv, long-press, fast-forward, rewind

It seems that, by default, Exoplayer FFWD and RWD buttons on Android TV do not accept long presses and require the user to press the D-PAD center button repeatedly to seek through the video.

Is there a way to enable repeated presses effect by long pressing? Tried with `isLongClickable` property but it does not seem to work.